# How to tell an MVC 4 View to return a JSON result with a sub route

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

What I want is a solution for the next problem:
1. I have an MVC 4 view + controller that renders Index and another for Details
2. to access that information I go to `http://localhost:1234/Movies` and to `http://localhost:1234/Movies/1` (for details)
3. I want to create a new route `http://localhost:1234/json/Movies` and `http://localhost:1234/json/Movies/1`
4. in the Method of Index I want the code to be like:

```
public ActionResult Index(string format)
        {
            return View(db.Movies.ToList());
        }
```

or

```
public ActionResult Index(string format)
        {
            return ChooseView(db.Movies.ToList());
        }
```

and I want the view to render the corrent (html\json) according to the route.

Is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: You question is not clear. What do you mean by `Chooseview`? and what does this mean: `I want the view to render the corrent (html\json) according to the route.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## In your controller

```
public class MoviesController : Controller
{
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult Index(string format)
    {
        return ToResult(db.Movies.ToList(), format);
    }
}
```

This will make `/Movies` get the HTML page rendered by the view `Index.cshtml` and `/Movies?format=json` get the list of movies as JSON data.

## Helper method

```
public static ActionResult ToResult(object data, string format)
{
    if (format == "json")
    {
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        return View(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use return Json(data)

for detail visit

http://programming-pages.com/2012/10/24/json-with-asp-net-mvc-4/